# sonarqube displays all projects on Home page with out login

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am using sonar community edition version 7.0. After sonnar-scanner -X in root  Project when i navigate to the sonarqube link  https:xxx.xx.xx.xxx:9000 i can see the projects are being displaced in home page with out login and any one can see that sonar report.

I have unchecked All the options for Anyone. I am using a new user and added to administrator group using that user in sonar properties file.

any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this website of the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=11635271#content/view/11635271):

> To force user authentication, log in as a system administrator, go
>   to **Administration > Configuration > General Settings > Security**, and
>   set the *Force user authentication* property to true.

And then there is more info about the different authentification mecanisms:

- SonarQube built-in users/groups database.
- external identity providers such as an LDAP server.
- HTTP Headers (property sonar.web.sso.enable in sonar.properties).

And also about the users and about the default admin credentials:

- Login: admin
- Password: admin